# Vim что то с интерфейсом

Tags: windows, vim

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скачал редактор Vim запустил а тут это...
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А так вим это консольный редактор, разве не так? В какой среде вы его запускаете?

Comment: это gvim - vim с gui. Вот только почему его так расколбасило - не понятно.

Comment: Похоже, что вим хочет выводить в utf-8, а ui решил, что это cp1251. А вот что в меню происходит - ...

Comment: У меня было подобное. Точного решения не помню, но если память не подводит - надо в конфиге вима настраивать кодировки. И, если правильно помню, для текста и для гуи в gvim разные параметры надо настраивать